# I can't set Big View Styles

Tags: android-notifications

I can't create a notification with Big View Styles. Support library issues ? My code is ok in Eclipse (no errors) but the notification shows only the contentTitle, the ContentText, the icon...that's it ! No extra lines in my notification ... What's wrong ? Thank you so much for your reply . Here's the code...

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Log.d("onMessage", String.valueOf(arg1));
    //Log.d("onMessage", "Receive a message");
    // Get the data from intent and send to notification bar
    String message = arg1.getExtras().getString("message");
    generateNotification3(arg0, message);
}


private static void generateNotification3(Context context, String message) {    
    NotificationCompat.Builder mbuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("lolo")
            .setContentText("text")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // requires VIBRATE permission
            /*
             * Sets the big view "big text" style and supplies the
             * text (the user's reminder message) that will be displayed
             * in the detail area of the expanded notification.
             * These calls are ignored by the support library for
             * pre-4.1 devices.
             */
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(message));

     // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app  
      Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, Fsa.class);  

      // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for  
      // the  
      // started Activity.  
      // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of  
      // your application to the Home screen.  
      TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);  

      // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)  
      stackBuilder.addParentStack(Fsa.class);  

      // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack  
      stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);  
      PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,  
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  
      mbuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);  

      NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  

      // mId allows you to update the notification later on.  
      mNotificationManager.notify(100, mbuilder.build());  

}
```

Comment: Did you attempt to expand the notification manually (touch it with two side-by-side fingers and drag downward)? Notifications will only automatically expand if they appear at the top of the list.

Comment: Gosh ! you're right !!! Excellent !!!! Is there a way to expand it programatically ? I added  .setOngoing(true) (to the top) but it's not expanded... (not really the top because the first one is a notification when I'm plugged to USB for tools developpement ). Thank you again my friend !

Comment: No, there's no way to expand it programmatically. The idea is that expansion policy is up to the user and the system UI; apps should just supply the data.

Comment: How come twitter's notifications are always expanded then?

Comment: U can create the custom notification like it :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44757879/3946958

Answer (score 14):

According to the official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#BigNotify), "big view appears only when the notification is expanded, which happens when the notification is at the top of the notification drawer, or when the user expands the notification with a gesture"
So, in order to have the Big View style, the notification shall be placed at the top of list.

To do that, When you create your notification please add:

```
setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
```

so it will be placed always in the top position of the list when it is received (of course if the user doesn't open the notification drawer and other notifications with maximum priority arrive, then it's not guaranteed that yours will be still at the top).

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that it will go to the top of the list, as well, it is against best practices. The P_MAX flag is not to be used in the case, and as well, there are many times when this still wouldn't work (ex. ongoing event flag). This question is still valid and open as such. 
If you have a working solution, please edit your post.