# How to use both BigTextStyle and BigPictureStyle in setStyle Notification?

Tags: android, push-notification

I am trying to  use both BigTextStyle and BigPictureStyle in my notification.But setStyle accepts only one style.

My code:

```
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
mBuilder.setVisibility(1);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon1);
mBuilder.setContentTitle(title.toString());
bigTextStyle.bigText(description.toString());
//mBuilder.setSubText(bigText.toString());
if (bigImage != null && !bigImage.toString().equals("")) {
    mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(ImageUtil.getBitmapFromUrl(bigImage.toString())));
}
mBuilder.setStyle(bigTextStyle);
mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

How can i use both ?. I want to show text(with line breaks) along with the image!

Comment: any update on this topic ??
using BigPictureStyle with BigTextStyle ...

Comment: yeah, its quite easy.Create your own notification layout!
You can design your xml and add it to notification.
For more details:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for late reply..Actually i was also faced the same problem and got the solution, so i am thinking that it can help for other user.
As we can NOT use the both `BigTextStyle` and `BigPictureStyle` method of the `NotificationCompat.Builder` than we can create the *`CustomView`*.

We can use the `setCustomBigContentView(RemoteViews)` method of `NotificationCompat.Builder` and create our own view to show the Big Image with Big text.

Please check the below code for it:-

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("YOUR_APP_NAME");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(body);
        notificationBuilder.setTicker("YOUR_APP_NAME");
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
        notificationBuilder.setCustomBigContentView(remoteView("YOUR_MESSAGE_TO_SHOW"));///IT IS THE MAIN METHOD WHICH WE USE TO INFLATE OR CREATE THE CUSTOM VIEW
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon(notificationBuilder));
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationBuilder.build());
```

Below is the RemoteViews which we have called from our `setCustomBigContentView()` method

```
 private RemoteViews remoteView(String message)
    {
        RemoteViews views;
        views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_HERE);
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.YOUR_BIG_IMAGE_ID_FROM_LAYOUT, bitmap);
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.YOUR_APP_ID_FROM_LAYOUT, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.APP_ICON_OF_YOUR_APP));
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.YOUR_BIG_TEXTVIEW_ID_FROM_LAYOUT, message);
        return views;
    }
```

I have created the custom notification like it[image: Custom Notification example]

Comment: That's a great solution.
How do you fetch layout files from Resource inside a service class?

Comment: I have just explained it by using the `RemoteViews`