# How to display BigPicture and Multiline text together in FCM Push notification for xamarin

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to display an expanded image as well as multiline text in my push notification. I am able to use either NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle or NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle . But I need to have them both.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: You could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44757879/7063418)